# Android cannot resolve play-services symbols

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

When trying to compile, I get the following errors:

```
Error:(59, 13) error: cannot find symbol class InstanceID
Error:(59, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable InstanceID
Error:(60, 59) error: package R does not exist
Error:(61, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable GoogleCloudMessaging
Error:(88, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable LocalBroadcastManager
Error:(117, 9) error: cannot find symbol class GcmPubSub
Error:(117, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable GcmPubSub
```

This is in a module, which is compiled as dependent on play-services:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0    compile
```

I have tried cleaning and building, invalidating the cache and restarting. What am I missing here? Why can't it find the `play-services` library?

Comment: Could you post your whole build.gradle file?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke I just clicked on "Analyze" -> "Analyze Module Dependencies" and clicked on google-play-services and it began recognizing the dependencies and those error disappeared. Sooo... not sure what was happening.